# WP_Query with UNIX timestamp in meta query

Tags: meta-query, timestamp

now idea why this isn't working, please point me in the right direction!

Here's my main query;

```
$events = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_event_date',
                'value' => time(),
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '<'    
            ),
        ),
    ) );
```

Each post has a custom field (_event_date) which is saved as a UNIX timestamp. I simply need to compare time() to this value to get posts with an older timestamp or posts with a newer timestamp. Here's the SQL that WP generates;

`SELECT   wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_event_date' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) < '1419072968' )
) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC`

Is this the correct way to query by a UNIX value? I've noticed there are other `type` settings, such as "date", "time" and so on. None of these seem to work.

Many thanks.

Comment: This looks fine to me (you should maybe use `UNSIGNED` instead of `NUMERIC` but it's not important). Are you sure you have `_event_date` meta data?! Try doing a `SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_event_date';` and see what you get...

Comment: @bonger Yes, I've done this query, it returns 3 results. 2 are older, and 1 is in the future. It's very odd, if the compare arg is "<" it returns two results, but it it's set to ">" it returns nothing!

Comment: Ah so it's almost working! Can only suggest maybe the one in the future isn't published?

Comment: Argh! As it turned out, the missing post was set as scheduled. I'm using the "fakerpress" plugin which generates dummy content, and I assume I picked a date range which meant some of the posts were scheduled to be published in the future. It's always an absolute pain to fall over such easy mistakes!! Thanks for your help.